what is type swap

hi, some one help me.
I don't know what kind of swap is this, the buying and selling time is the same, and how to get it on solana.
Thank you so much

I’m voting to close this question because this site is for dev q&a, not explorer support

These swaps look like an arbitrage transaction, which the same amount of tokens is exchanged multiple times to take advanatage on price differences.
